# Another option to POST redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring where a requestMapping is defined to a method which stores all the entries a user makes on a form called "a.html" and the method being used is a POST. On submitting this a.html comes back to the page it is called from which is index.html but the URL still says "a.html" and on doing a refresh action it tries to resubmit which is causing an issue unacceptable to us.

Is there a way to POST and on form submission return back to index.html with the URL saying "index.html" and not "a.html". Note we cannot use redirection because the html is sent to another proxy which doesn't support redirection. Any other suggestion than redirection on POST ?

```
@RequestMapping("/a.html", "RequestMethod.POST")
public ModelAndView create()
{
 // code to fill up the form
 return new ModelAndView() //springframework.servlet

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return an Redirect:

```
 return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/index.html", true));
```

*Best practice: always return a redirect on every Request that change something on the server*

Comment: But a service proxy that I make calls to doesn't support redirection. Any other ideas ?